# botón submit elimina los formularios de mi formset y no guarda ningún dato (django)

Tags: javascript, django, submit

estoy tratando de hacer un formset dinámico con js y django, pero cada vez que trato de guardar datos, se recarga la pagina sin formularios y no se guarda nada en la base de datos, no se que pueda estar fallando y me urge encontrar la respuesta. Por favor, por piedad jejeje

este es mi view

```
class FormsetProveedor(FormView):
template_name="nproveedor.html"
form_class=formset_factory(ProveedorModelForm, extra=1)

def form_valid(self,form):
    for f in form:
        print(f.cleaned_data["Nombre_P"])
    return super(FormsetProveedor,self).form_valid(form)
```

mi modelo super básico

```
class Proveedor(models.Model):
Nombre_P=models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Nombre_P
```

mi form también muy básico

```
class ProveedorModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=Proveedor
    fields=["Nombre_P",]
    labels={
        "Nombre_P":"Nombre de proveedor",
    }
```

y mi template

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block head %}Nuevo Proveedor{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1 class="text-center">{{titulo}}</h1>
        <p></p>
        <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.mangement_form }}
                {% for fo in form %}
            <div class="card" style="padding:20px" id="f_proov">
                {{ fo|crispy }}
                <br>
            </div>
                {% endfor %}
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
        </form>
        <button type="button" onclick="agregar_inputs()">Agregar</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function agregar_inputs(){
        var total_forms = "0";
        //nuevo label e input
        var nuevo_label_nombre=document.createElement('label');
        nuevo_label_nombre.innerHTML='Nombre de proveedor';
        var nuevo_input_nombre=document.querySelector('#id_form-0-Nombre_P').cloneNode(true);
        nuevo_input_nombre.name='form-' + total_forms.value + '-Nombre_P';
        nuevo_input_nombre.id='id_form-' + total_forms.value + '-Nombre_P';

        document.querySelector('#f_proov').appendChild(nuevo_label_nombre);
        document.querySelector('#f_proov').appendChild(nuevo_input_nombre);

        total_forms.value=parseInt(total_forms.value)+1;
    }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Así se ve la pagina inicialmete

[image: asi se presenta la página inicialmente]

[image: asi se ve al presionar submit]

Asi se ve al presionar "enviar"

Comment: si `var total_forms = "0"` sería un string, esperaría que `total_forms.value` dé un error ( al margen de que siempre sería 0 ) probá usar un `input type hidden` para guardar el total o si lo queres mas javascriptoso con un `data-totalforms` o un count de los childs o el lenght de un queryselector por clases etc

Comment: Hola, intenté de muchas formas y no lo logré, al parecer tiene que ver con la versión de django 3.2.16 que entra en conflicto con javascript y no logran hacer un match de los nombres del form en html y los nombres nativos del modelo que creé  :(, aún así, te agradezco la ayuda :)